# How to fix "Key for the principal <principal user> not available in <keytab file>" in Java 18 Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, keytab

I am trying to connect to Kafka using keytab file to login but found this following exceptions and authentication failed;

> Found unsupported keytype (23) for AAA@EXAMPLE.TH
>
> 2023-07-17 09:56:54 Key for the principal AAA@EXAMPLE.TH not available in /etc/example.keytab
>
> 2023-07-17 09:56:54 [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
>
> 2023-07-17 09:56:54 Unable to obtain password from user

I double-checked the jaas file that I put the right path for keytab file but it seemed not find the keytab file in that specified path.

Here's the values in my jaas file;

```
KafkaClient { 
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        debug=true
        isInitiator=true
        doNotPrompt=true

        keyTab="/etc/example.keytab"
        principal="AAA@EXAMPLE.TH";
};
```

And krb5.conf values;

```
# includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log 
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.TH
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ticket_lifetime = 7d
    #renew_lifetime = 15d
[realms]
    EXAMPLE.TH = {
        admin_server = example.th
        kdc = example.th
        default_domain = EXAMPLE.TH
    }
```

In addition, this is my application.properties file

```
## kafka security
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name=bigfoot
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location=./keyuat/godzilla.client.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password=godzilla007

## kafka consumer
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=godzilla01:9092,godzilla02:9092,godzilla03:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=godzilla_lookup
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
spring.kafka.topic.name=prod-godz
```

Could anyone help me fixing this exception? I am very new to Kafka and just started working as Java Developer about 10 months. So any comments or suggestions are welcome and appreciated. And I can provide more info if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The log message is clearly telling you that **it DID find the file** but it doesn't like the key _in_ the file. Specifically it found type 23=RC4-HMAC which is generally considered weak, and deprecated by IANA. Since you didn't configure permitted_enctypes it uses a default which excludes RC4 unless 'allow_weak_crypto' is set and I'm not clear where _that_ defaults; it may well be system dependent. The best solution is to get a key for a modern/strong algorithm (AES) but of course that depends on the KDC you are using.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your reply and suggest mr.Dave. I will discuss with the team about the key file and will update you again.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The keytab encryption type is ArcFour with HMAC/md5 so it's a weak encryp type right?. I've tried adding 'allow_weak_crypto' to krb5.conf and it works! I can connect to the cluster. However, I don't really know  about'allow_weak_crypto' much. are there any weakness or impacts to my cluster?

Comment: ArcFour is just an alternate name for RC4; see wikipedia. The applicable weaknesses of the RC4-HMAC enctype in Kerberos, which are due to the key hash as well as the encryption itself, are detailed in [the deprecating RFC 8429](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8429.html#section-5). What risks these cause in your environment could vary; to answer that you need a security expert familiar with your environment, such as your company's data/IT security officer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue is about Java version. My keytab encryption type is ArcFour with HMAC/md5 and Java 18 that I used for my app is not allow to read This keytab file. I've tried downgrading to Java 11 and connecting Kafka an it works fine without any additional values.

So the solution (in case of using Java version 18 and keytab encryption type is weak type) is to set additional value in krb5.conf "allow_weak_crypto = true". By the way, it also depends on the keytab encryption type, if the algorithm is modern or strong I don't think it is a problem.